# How do I mirror the faces of a cube (edit all of them when I edit one)?

Tags: faces, mirror

I'm trying to create a design for a retro-futuristic computer and I need the faces of a cube to look the same and see the results as I edit them, to see how the edges of the cube interact. Furthermore, if I want to one day be a professional at Blender, it will be a good skill to have. How do I do this? Thank you for any help. :)

Answer (score 15):

1. Use one or more mirror modifiers with a **mirror object**.
2. Use the array modifier with an **object offset**.
3. Use duplifaces displaying another object.

The third option suits your problem best, here is a step by step solution.

1. Add a plane ad duplicate it <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

[image]

2. Make sure both planes point to the same mesh datablock. If necessary, set the duplicated datablock to the same mesh. The mesh
   datablock in the object properties panel should display a **2** at the
   end.

[image]

Editing one plane now affects both, because they point to the same datablock.

[image]

3. Parent a plane to the cube <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, both should have the same location.

[image]

4. Set the duplication property of the cube to **Faces** (in the object properties panel).

[image]

5. Editing one of the planes will now affects all faces of the cube. The plane parented to the cube will not be rendered. I duplicated the plane to make the edits to it easier, since the other plane is hidden in the cube.

[image]

Comment: In Blender 2.8, the "duplication property" is now in "object properties">"instancing".  Reference: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/index.html