# Trying to duplicate changes across faces of a dodecahedron

Tags: faces, mirror

Can someone tell me how to duplicate changes made to one face of a dodecahedron to all the other faces?

For example if I extrude one face, I'd like the same thing to happen to the other faces!

I tried the steps here: [How do I mirror the faces of a cube (edit all of them when I edit one)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64963/how-do-i-mirror-the-faces-of-a-cube-edit-all-of-them-when-i-edit-one) but the duplicated faces ended up at odd angles.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain this result, using duplicate linked objects:

[image]

If you duplicate linked <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> all duplicates are sharing the same geometry.

So to do it from a dodecaedron:

[image]

The gif above was becoming to big, but you see the principle:

- Add a dodecahedron, enter edit mode, select and duplicate a face then separate it <kbd>P</kbd>
- Select this newly created face, duplicate linked <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> then rotate around the first axis (front view)
- Select the two faces, again duplicate linked and rotate along a second axis
- Do this until you obtain the 12 faces

Once your individual faces edit finished, you can come back to a single mesh doing the following:

[image]

- Select all the dupli objects
- Then in the menu, object/make single user/object and data, and validate for the selection (**edit**: in fact this step is not useful)
- Join them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
- Enter edit mode and remove doubles